# Rails 3 HABTM Strange Association: Project and Employee in a tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Hi guys I have to adapt an existing model to a new relation. I have this:

A Project has many Employees.
the Employees of a Project are organized in some kind of hierarchy (nothing fancy, I resolved this adding a parent_id for each employee to build the 'tree')

```
class Employee < AR:Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Employee'
    has_many :children, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_column => 'parent_id'  
end

class Project < AR:Base
   has_many :employees, 
end
```

That worked like a charm, now the new requirement is: The Employees can belong to many Projects at the same time, and the hierarchy will be different according to the project.

So I though I will need a new table to build the HABTM, and a new class to access the parent_id to build the tree. Something like

```
class ProjectEmployee < AR:Base
   belongs_to :project
   belongs_to :employee
   belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Employee' # <--- ??????
end

class Project < AR:Base
   has_many :project_employee
   has_many :employees, :through => :project_employee
end

class Employee < AR:Base 
   has_many :project_employee
   has_many :projects, :through => :project_employee
end
```

How can I access the *parent* and the children of an employee for a given project? I need to add and remove children as wish from the employees of a project.

Thank you!

Comment: The pluralized form of "child" is "children", and Rails knows it. ;)

Comment: rails yes, but i don't :P fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to rename things for better distinction, feels a bit clumsy still..

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_roles
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_roles
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_roles
  has_many :persons, :through => :project_roles
end

class ProjectRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "ProjectRole"
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "ProjectRole", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
end
```

Given some existing records:

```
person = Person.first
project = Project.first
manager = project.project_roles.first
```

Adding person:

```
project.project_roles.create(:person => person, :manager => manager)
```

Removing person:

```
person.project_roles.find_by_project_id(project.id).destroy
```

--edit

[Rails association extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) could have some use here.

Comment: great! is there a way to access all the subordinates of a manager in a straight 'rails' way? (eg. allowing me to use manager.subordinates << person or manager.subordinates = [a,b,c] ?)

Comment: Maybe that could be a method in `ProjectRole` like `manager.add_as_subordinate(a,b,c)`.